# Failed to locate executable /usr/sbin/prometheus-nginxlog-exporter

Tags: ubuntu, prometheus, wsl2

Не запускаетcя prometheus на wsl ubunru 22.04

```
$ sudo systemctl status prometheus
× prometheus.service - NGINX metrics exporter for Prometheus
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/prometheus.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-02-10 14:48:19 MSK; 3min 12s ago
    Process: 367 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/prometheus-nginxlog-exporter -config-file /etc/prometheus-nginxlog-exporter.hcl (c>
   Main PID: 367 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 10 14:48:19 DESKTOP-NOA9SBD systemd[1]: Started NGINX metrics exporter for Prometheus.
Feb 10 14:48:19 DESKTOP-NOA9SBD systemd[367]: prometheus.service: Failed to locate executable /usr/sbin/prometheus-ngin>
Feb 10 14:48:19 DESKTOP-NOA9SBD systemd[367]: prometheus.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/prometheus-ngi>
Feb 10 14:48:19 DESKTOP-NOA9SBD systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 10 14:48:19 DESKTOP-NOA9SBD systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: «Failed to locate executable» — ну значит вы пытаетесь запускать несуществующую программу

Answer (score 0):

похоже из репозитория установилась старая версия, с новой таких проблем нет